# Virtual Machine Scale Set support

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

Does the currently azure-java-sdk support Virtual Machine Scale Set creation? I've checked the java docs in http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/ and could not find anything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The current Azure SDK for Java supports VM Scale Sets. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java

Earlier answer:
I reviewed the Javadocs of Azure SDK for Java and compared with [the REST APIs of Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt589023.aspx). I'm afraid my answer for your question is that Azure SDK for Java not suppport VMSS with Azure Resource Management now.

So you can only try to use the Virtual Machine REST APIs to support VMSS.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SDK for Java 1.0.0-Beta1, which is currently available on MavenCentral does have support for VM Scale Sets